# KO3/Kohana3: How do we escape quotes (double and single) before saving to db with ORM using values()?

Tags: php, database, kohana, escaping

I allow users to submit a question, and they should be able to have single quotes in their title.
Currently, if a title contains a single quote, it will submit properly.
`$question->values($post_data); $question->save();`

Any ideas on how I can set Kohana to escape that single quote / escape my information automatically? I would like to avoid having to addslashes() every input and removeslashes() every display...

Thank you so much, SO community!
(This question is crossposted at http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=6525)

Comment: You've show us the `save()` method but in the error you got `SELECT` one. You missed something.

Comment: show us the code that builds the query. I doubt it's the `$question->title`. There must be a sequence of ORM method calls that generates the 'match against' clause in the query.

Comment: I realized that my issue wasn't escaping on input, it was trying to match on read.  Issue has been resolved by escaping the value that I match against just before the sql statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you should never use addslashes() to escape DB values at all. Especially not in Kohana, since values are "escaped" while being saved ( example you're giving is ORM one, you can always mess up a custom DB query to get a MySQL injection / broken query ).

If you don't want something to get escaped, wrap it in `DB::expr()` ( so it'll return an instance of Database_Expression, which doesn't get automatically escaped ).

To escape a value manually, use `Database::quote()` (not static, call it through your Database object, e.g. `$db->quote($value)` ).

Answer (score 0):

But! Kohana has a problem with backticks (`). This is a system's symbol.

```
            elseif(preg_match('/\`/', $value))//if a backtick
            {
                return str_replace('\'', '', $value);//'value'=>value!!! 
            }

    return $this->escape($value);
```